# Share a method between two classes with buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, class, methods

I have two Classes in C# with Windows Forms, let us call them `One.cs` and `Two.cs`. On both Classes I have two exactly the same Buttons, with the same function and the same name.

Now I have a function, which disables among other things one of these Buttons. Simplified it looks like that:

```
public static void Something(){ 
btnOne.Enabled = false; }
```

And now I want to share this function Something between my two classes `One.cs` and `Two.cs`. How can I do that?

I already tried to made a new static Class, with this function and tried to access it from class One and Two. But the problem is the Button, which I want to access...

Comment: Looks like you want to *inherit* `One` and `Two` from some *base class* (base form in your case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you need a reference to the button to be enabled/disabled. This you have to provide it within your method-parameters:

```
public static void Something(Button btn)
{ 
    btn.Enabled = false; 
}
```

Now you can simply call it from everywhere in your code using `MyStaticClass.Something(btnOne)` (or `btnTwo` when in `Two`-class).

Comment: I had to use: `public static void Something(System.Windows.Forms.Button btn)` but it worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple options.

1. Create  a base class and have that function in that base class. Now **inherit** the same and use anywhere you want.
2. ***Create a common class*** . Include every function that you want to have across the application. Now create an object of that class and use it. (you need a reference for the button).
3. Create an ***interface*** and have that `virtual` function. Now override that function in the classes where you want and use it as per need.